# Firebase Cloud Functions onCreate auth not working correclty

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I have a  Cloud Function that triggers when a user creates an account and updates a value inside my Firestore.

Everything worked perfectly before, but since this morning (I didn't change a single line of code in my functions) it stopped updating the value in the Firestore.

The weird thing is that `onDelete` is working.

Here are both functions:

```
exports.accountCreate = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
    console.log(user.uid);
    const userCounterRef = admin.firestore().collection("data").doc("userCounter");

    userCounterRef.update({
        userCounter: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1),
    });
});

exports.accountDelete = functions.auth.user().onDelete((user) => {
    console.log(user.uid);
    const userCounterRef = admin.firestore().collection("data").doc("userCounter");

    userCounterRef.update({
        userCounter: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(-1),
    });
});
```

I don't see any `errors` in my logs:

[image]

The only thing that looks weird are the two logs that I see quite often:

> Exception from a finished function: Error: 4 DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: Deadline exceeded
>
> Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take note of the message:

> Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value

Cloud Functions must return a promise that resolves when all async work is complete.  Right now, you are ignoring the promises returned by `update`.  This means you have no guarantee that the work will complete - at best it will finish randomly.

You can fix this easily by returning the promise from both functions:

```
userCounterRef.update(...);
```

I suggest already reading the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) to understand this better. You must absolutely understand how JS promises work and use them correctly in order work with Cloud Functions effectively.

Comment: fixed it by simply returning `return userCounterRef.update(..)`.. Thanks! Werid that it worked for almost half a year quite alright :D thanks!